# event.altKey on the keyup event is false although the key is "down"

Tags: javascript, browser, addeventlistener, keyup

I want to add an HTML class to an element as long as the <kbd>Alt</kbd> modifier is pressed. The following observations were made using a current version of Google Chrome (same behavior in Opera).

```
const rootElement = document.querySelector(':root')

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.altKey) {
        rootElement.classList.add('modifier-pressed')
    }
})

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    // This should be `event.altKey`, but it’s never `true`.
    // Checking for the actual key code works ¯\_(ツ)_/¯:

    // if (event.keyCode === 18) {
    if (event.altKey) {
        rootElement.classList.remove('modifier-pressed')
    }
})
```

The first part works fine. Listening for the `keydown` event allows me to add the class when the key is pressed.

The second part does not work. Even though the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is *down* at the moment the `keyup` event is fired, the `event.altKey` property is set to `false`. This is contradictionary to the reported `event.keyCode`: 18 (the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key). Atleast the way I understand it.

The [Mozilla Developer Network page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup#Properties) for the event lists the property `event.altKey` as expected: It should be `true` when it the key was *down* when firing.

So this is pretty unexpected as far as I’m concerned. However it gets worse: In Firefox, on both events (`keydown` and `keyup`), the property `event.altKey` is set to `false` while the key code is as expected (18).

How to riddle this? Did I understand it right and this behavior is indeed unexpected or is my understanding wrong? What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to w3c docs altKey event attribute returns true if it's press and false if not, so your code is working right. On keydown event alt is pressed - so it returns keycode 18 and true , on keyup alt is not pressed, so the result is 18 and false.

Check link - https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#dom-keyboardevent-altkey

`KeyboardEvent.altKey : true if Alt modifier was active, otherwise false`

Comment: I quote the same information from the MDN page I linked. I assumed that when the alt key was pressed, it would still be true, but it’s not.

Comment: The only thing I don’t understand now is why Firefox reports `event.altKey === false` on `keydown` and Chrome reports `event.altKey === true`.

Comment: Probably some issue in firefox browser then. But as per MDN it is said that - `altKey Read only boolean true if the alt key was down when the event was fired. false otherwise.`  Can you try the link `https://jsfiddle.net/ashvin777/Lz86ufkw/` whether this works as expected in Firefox or not

Comment: It doesn’t. `event.altKey === false` in `keydown` when pressing the alt key. In Chrome, it’s `true`.

Comment: Ok. Then it could be a issue in firefox browser. Are you using the stable version of firefox ?